# Iterating through the python and pandas loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops

What is the best way to look into how the loop works thourh iterations?
I have defined 2 functions which have to go in one after another (the 2nd gets the result of the 1st and works it through).

Ultimately I need 2-line pandas dataframe as the output.

Sample code below.

```
def candle_data (
    figi, 
    int1 = candle_resolution,
    from1 = previous_minutemark,
    to1 = last_minutemark
    ):
    response = market_api.market_candles_get(figi = ticker_figi_test, from_ = from1, to = to1, interval = int1)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.parse_json().dict()
    else:
        return print(response.parse_error())

def response_to_pandas_df (response):
    df_candles = pd.DataFrame(response['payload'])
    df_candles = pd.json_normalize(df_candles['candles'])
    df_candles = df_candles[df_candles['time'] >= previous_minutemark]
    df_candles = df_candles[['c', 'figi','time']]
    df_candles_main = df_candles_template.append(df_candles)
    return df_candles_main
```

then I call the functions in a loop:

```
ticker_figi_list = ["BBG000CL9VN6", "BBG000R7Z112"]

df_candles_main = df_candles_template

for figi in ticker_figi_list:
    response = candle_data(figi)
    df_candles_main = response_to_pandas_df(response)
```

But in return I get only 1 row of data for the 1st FIGI in the list.

I suppose, that I define the `candle_data()` function with `figi_ticker_test` which contain only 1 value may be the case. But I'm not sure how to work this around.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What means "in return" here? Which variable do you finally evaluate?

Comment: I get a pandas dataframe containing only 1 row with only 1 evaluated figi. I need all data for all figis in list `ticker_figi_list`.

`df_candles_main` dataframe should have data for 2 figis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is you are calling the api with `figi = ticker_figi_test`. I assume ticket_figi_test is equal to the first figi in your list and so you aren't actually calling the api with different figi on each iteration.  Try changing to the following:

```
response = market_api.market_candles_get(figi = figi, from_ = from1, to = to1, interval = int1)
```

Comment: This helps, thank you! Will finalize another issue that has appeared (with `append()` function) and will get back to your post.

Comment: Solution verified.
Thx again!